# Post via OpenGraph to Company Page NOT user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

As I am learning and getting familiar with the FB OpenGraph API I am finding that I am lacking some of the basics. For example I see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/news.publishes) that I use the action type news.publishes to post an article. However the access_token is for the user owning the page and thus it will go to their news feed and not the page (in this case their company page). Is that correct?

If I understand correctly then how does one get it to post to a specific page. Is there an access_token collection you iterate through till you find the one for the company page?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use /PAGE_ID/feed? Where page id is the numerical assigned by facebook..or the text friendly name you used.